# Axios call returns net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, axios

Whenever I make an axios call to an the '/login' endpoint, I keep getting the following error printed in my browser console. I've included the server.js file and the file from where I'm making the call for your reference.

Dependencies installed in the client folder: axios, react, react-dom, react-router-dom
Dependencies installed in the server folder: cors, express, node, spotify-web-api-node

```
GET http://localhost:3001/login net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

index.js file

```
import axios from 'axios'


const Profile = () => {

  const login = () => {
    console.log("testing login function - client")

    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/login")
    .then(() => {
      console.log("success")
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("error")
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="profile">
      .
      .
      .
        <div className="button">
          <button onClick={() => login()} className="btn">Log In</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Profile
```

server.js file

```
const SpotifyWebAPINode = require('spotify-web-api-node')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()
app.use(cors)

// This file is copied from: https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/blob/master/examples/tutorial/00-get-access-token.js

const scopes = [
  'user-top-read',
  'user-library-read',
  'playlist-read-private',
  'playlist-read-collaborative',
  'playlist-modify-public',
  'playlist-modify-private',
]

// credentials are optional
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebAPINode({
  clientId: 'XXX',
  clientSecret: 'XXX',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3001/callback',
})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log("testing login endpoint - server")

  res.redirect(spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes))
})

app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
  const error = req.query.error
  const code = req.query.code
  const state = req.query.state

  if (error) {
    console.error('Callback Error:', error)
    res.send(`Callback Error: ${error}`)
    return
  }

  spotifyApi
    .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then((data) => {
      const access_token = data.body['access_token']
      const refresh_token = data.body['refresh_token']
      const expires_in = data.body['expires_in']

      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token)
      spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refresh_token)

      console.log('access_token:', access_token)
      console.log('refresh_token:', refresh_token)

      console.log(
        `Sucessfully retreived access token. Expires in ${expires_in} s.`,
      )
      res.send('Success! You can now close the window.')

      setInterval(async () => {
        const data = await spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken()
        const access_token = data.body['access_token']

        console.log('The access token has been refreshed!')
        console.log('access_token:', access_token)
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token)
      }, (expires_in / 2) * 1000)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error getting Tokens:', error)
      res.send(`Error getting Tokens: ${error}`)
    })
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server live on port 3001')
})
```

Comment: In the front-end, you need to actually send the user to your /login URL, not fetch it with Axios, so that Spotify can do its work and either autologin the user, or present them a form so that they can authorize your app to access their account.

Comment: @blex but isn't the endpoint being called? I'm not even seeing "testing login endpoint - server" in my console. I took your advice and changed the button to an anchor that sends the user to http://localhost:3001/login but it's still stuck

Comment: RESOLVED: app.use(cors) should be app.use(cors())